# Node js nested async call

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

I want to do async call from my getData function to getImage function but i am unable to get return data from getImage().Since the getData() does't wait for the completion of getImage(),as getImage() has further async db calls and therefore getData() always returns undefined.

What is the best way to do this instead doing nested callbacks?

```
var getData  = function(id){  
async.series([            
        function(callback){                    
                  var res = getImages(id);                                                                     
                  callback(null, res);                                           
        }
    ],
  // optional callback
  function(err, results){

     if (err) {                      
         console.log("ERROR : " + err);
      }else 
      {           
              console.log("Result: "+results);              
      }
  });

}



var getImages  = function(id){ 

  async.series([            
        function(callback){ 
              Image.find({id: id }).exec(                    
                  function(err, image) { 
                    if (err) {
                         console.log(err);                                
                         callback(err, 0);
                      }else 
                      {     console.log("Count: "+ image.length);                                                                      
                            callback(null, image);                                              
                      }
              });                         
        }
    ],
  // optional callback
  function(err, results){

     if (err) {                     
         console.log("ERROR : " + err);
      }else 
      {                                 

              return results;          

      }
  });

}


getData(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you need to wait for `getImages()` to return, and you do that using promises.
Use any promise library, like `q` for instance:

```
var q = require('q')
...
var getImages  = function(id){
  var deferred = q.defer();
  ...
  //do async logic that that evaluates some res obj you wish to return
  db.find(..., function() {
    deferred.resolve(res);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then, from `getData()`, you call it in the following matter:

```
getImages(id).then(
  function(res) {
    callback(null, res);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log("error:" + err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using async - just use the `waterfall` functionality: https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback

This way you will be able to run functions one after another and wait for the previous to finish, while still getting it's return value.